# apply CSS to first matching element with ID or Class

Tags: html, css

I have following code:

```
<html>
...
<div id="rdMainBody">
...
</div>
...
<div id="rdMainBody">
...
</div>
...
<div id="rdMainBody">
...
</div>
...
</html>
```

Is it possible to write in css something that only affects the first match with a div, id="rdMainBody" ?

Adding a class is not a possible solution in my case.

Greetings.

Comment: Same `id` for multiple elements is invalid HTML. That aside, you can have a look at the `:first-child` or `first-of-type` selectors depending on whether the first `div` with that `id` is the first child of its parent (or) the first `div` under its parent.

Comment: Remove these and change for classes etc as mentioned above, this is invalid, then use first-child or other similar.

Comment: I use the Logi engine, which generates theses divs, but I need to change stuff in only the first id, which also runs in a frame, so things get complicated.

Comment: "*Adding a class is not a possible solution in my case*" - before anything else, fix the bug that's preventing you from adding classes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rdMainBody {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  margin : 5px;
}
.rdMainBody:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="rdMainBody"></div>
<div class="rdMainBody"></div>
<div class="rdMainBody"></div>
```

Comment: you should give an explanation rather than just the code.

Comment: @dippas An 'id' can only be used once in valid code. You must use classes. Period.

Comment: I Know that, you should explain that in your answer, so OP know why you are using that code.

Answer (score 0):

The **:first-child** CSS selector select the first element.
[W3School Example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)

`#rdMainBody:first-child {your css}`

Answer (score 0):

As some guys said, adding the same id for multiple elements is not a valid HTML code. But if you need to do this, i would use jquery to add some class to the first id with desired name and style the class in CSS.

when you select id that is used multiple times in document, it only selects the first one, so you must select them by attribute like so "[id=rdMainBody]". This will get all the elements and then you can use first() to select the first one.

```
$(".main").find("[id=rdMainBody]").first().addClass("some_class");
```

By all means, it is not good to have more ids with the same name. Please use class instead.

Below is my jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/michalchovanak/q0q3vyud/